wFewer formats can be selected when compressing files in file manager
When compressing files using file roller or on desktop, there are many extensions can be selected. But when compressing in file manager(nautilus), there are only 4(zip, encrypted zip, tar.xz and 7z) can be selected.
I can't provide a screenshot of that.

Thanks for the information. Yes, fileroller is a different program, and it offers more formats to compress.
